# How is it possible that I can make an instance from a class in which some member methods aren't defined yet? (C++)

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm comparatively new to C++ so I tested some things out in Xcode, and found a really weird thing.
This is my 'Testing.h' file

```
#ifndef Testing_h
#define Testing_h
class Testing{
private:
    int a;
public:
    Testing(int a=3);
    void hey(int b);
};
#endif
```

This is my 'Testing.cpp' file

```
#include "Testing.h"
Testing::Testing(int a){
    a = 4;
}
```

And finally, this is the 'main.cpp' file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Testing.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
Testing a;
//Apparently not completing the definitions of every abstract methods in the class is not a problem
}
```

I only declared 'void hey(int b)' in 'Testing.h' but have not defined it in 'Testing.cpp'. So I was wondering how it is possible for the compiler to successfully compile the 'main.cpp' without having enough information of 'void hey(int b)'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no abstract methods here. One method is declared but undefined, but you don't call it, so no link error.

Comment: 'void hey(int b)' is **NOT** an *abstract* method - it is simply a declaration of a method - the fact that you don't have an implementation for it does not matter until you actually use it. 'virtual void hey(int b) = 0' would keep you from instantiating 'Testing', however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you never require there to be a definition for `hey()`.

You can require a definition by calling it, for example :

```
a.hey(42);
```

And you'll see that the linker isn't too happy because `hey` is an undefined reference.

Answer (score 0):

> `Testing a;//Apparently not completing the definitions of every abstract methods in the class is not a problem`

You defined constructor with default value `a=3` but calling both constructor argument and class parameter the same name is bad practice.
Instead you can write this:

```
//Testing.h
#ifndef Testing_h
#define Testing_h
using namespace std;
class Testing{
private:
    int number;
public:
    Testing(int a=3): number(a = 4){}//it's the same as your implementation in cpp file
    void hey(int b);
    int getNumber() {return number;}
};
#endif


//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Testing.h"
int main()
{
    Testing object;
    cout<<object.getNumber();// returns 4

    return 0;
}
```

**And why `hey` compiles?**

During building your project compiler translates your source code into object code by verifying the syntax. After that process linker checks the definitions marked by whole phrases. Source code is compiled from each file provided. Linker doesn't care for the implementation presence, it only looks it up if a method is used by the program. So even without implementation of `hey` your program compiles.

**Last remark**

It's discouraged to include .cpp files use headers instead. Sometimes you can get yourself into multiple definitions of the same functions causing compiler errors.